# Replace the number with np.nan comparing with array not with integer

Tags: numpy, replace, nan

When I try to replace the number in array with np.nan, I used the function such as:

```
X[X>9.] = np.nan
```

However, I would like to compare with the another array, not with number.

For example:

```
A = [5.09901951, 4.84148737, 3.72021505, 4.28952212, 3.87814389, 3.7094474]
X = [7.54950976, 2.02074369, 1.26010752, 3.14476106, 8.53907194, 10.0547237]
X[X>A] = np.nan
```

It doesn't seem to work. and also I don't want use for loop, because it would cause trouble, if the array size becomes bigger.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Isaac

Comment: It seems to work when I try iit. What is the error you get?

Comment: Are `A` and `X` arrays or lists?

Comment: @ayhan I did't do with array as hpaulj, Thank you and apologize for confusing you.

Comment: @hapulj Yes, you are right. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments @hpaulj:
if you change the lists to numpy arrays this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([5.09901951, 4.84148737, 3.72021505, 4.28952212, 3.87814389, 3.7094474])
X = np.array([7.54950976, 2.02074369, 1.26010752, 3.14476106, 8.53907194, 10.0547237])
X[X>A] = np.nan
```

X will be:

```
array([        nan,  2.02074369,  1.26010752,  3.14476106,         nan,
               nan])
```